# HTML/CSS. How do I stylize TD based on column data type

Tags: html, css

I have an ordinary `table/th/tr/td` block on a web page that displays tabular data. Data columns may be reordered:

```
product|price|date
price|product|date
date|product|price
```

...  e.t.c

but the same order for a single render:

```
Microsoft|100|01-01-2020
Google|200|02-02-2019
```

or

```
100|Microsoft|01-01-2020
200|Google|02-02-2019
```

I have to stylize product/price/date columns in a table (for instance: "product" is bold, and "date" is italic). Finally, it looks ugly:

```
<td style="font-weight: bold">Microsoft</td> ...
```

When I render
`table/th/tr/td`
I know what data is in every column. May I use CSS to solve my task without applying styles/classes directly to every single cell?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, style-wise, there are the `<colgroup>` and `<col>` elements, which allow you to set _some_ CSS rules: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns

Comment: Do you load content with JS to the cells? Maybe you could get the TD element while loading data to the cells and add that to the Map objects for example, then loop through the maps and style all TD elements depending on the content.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can! You can use `td:nth-child(x) {}` to apply all styles to that column

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JS to decide weather to apply styles to which data cell.

Like:

You could have predefined set of css classes in array and then inject where required.
This is useful for dynamic data in s.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an specific class to your cell for example for name cells ->n , for date-> cells d  and so on then with css you can style according to that class for example if you want to bold all names do like this:

```
.n{
    font-weight:bold
  }
```